# How to move bootstrap banner to right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I want to locate the navbar to the right of the screen. It seemed trivial before I tried to do that.

Here is what I did:

index.html

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

and in bootstrap.css I floated the navbar-brand to right:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

But it is still on the left! How to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps a demo? It's not really clear to me what you mean by "move the navbar to the right"

Comment: if you're using bootstrap there should be a class like `pull-right` for moving items to the right

Comment: If you mean "align the text to right", there also is the `text-right` class

Comment: have you tried ul.navbar navbar-right

Comment: Or this - http://jsfiddle.net/3mkLn3cm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its actually the `.navbar-header` that is floated left by default, so adding a float to `.navbar-brand` will not actually change anything.

```
.navbar-header {
  float: right;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/hL35p5ha/)

Or adding the `.navbar-right` class to the `.navbar-header` would also work.

```
<div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
```